# Can we use multiple webservice call in single intentservice's onHandleIntent()?

Tags: android, intentservice

As i know intentservice's OnHandleIntent run on separate thread same like asynctask, so can we use two or more webservice call in single IntentService? If we do so.. how android will execute both webservice call? Means is it return result of first webserive call and then execute another?

Comment: yes you can use multiple webservices in single intentService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, as much as you could perform many sync http call in a separate thread.
The caveat is that you need to perform *synchronous* http calls (if you use okhttp or retrofit you need to look for the blocking flavour) and that they will obviously be serialized.

Comment: *The caveat is that you need to perform synchronous http calls* this is important. Also note that if you're just doing http calls in your service, you are better off using a regular service so you don't have to worry about the synchronicity

Comment: I edit question..How android execute webserive calls in same scenario?Please suggest

Comment: Yes, since they are synchronous and so blocking...

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple webservices call in single `IntentService`